# MacOS MTKView metal self.device.newBufferWithBytes crashes with assert

Tags: objective-c, macos, metal

I want to draw a simple triangle and it crashes after I am trying to create `MTLBuffer`.

```
static float vertexes[] = {
        0.0, 0.5, 0.0,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0,
        0.5, -0.5f, 0.0
};

id <MTLBuffer> buffer = [self.device newBufferWithBytes:vertexes
        length:sizeof(vertexes) options:MTLResourceStorageModePrivate];
```

Here is the assert:

```
-[MTLDebugDevice newBufferWithBytes:length:options:]:392: failed assertion `storageModePrivate incompatible with ...WithBytes variant of newBuffer'
```

So how to create a buffer from the vertexes using MTLResourceStorageModePrivate option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must create a temporary blit buffer and use it to copy the contents to the private buffer. Here's example code:

```
buffer = [self.device newBufferWithLength:sizeof( vertexes )
                   options:MTLResourceStorageModePrivate];

id<MTLBuffer> blitBuffer = [self.device newBufferWithBytes:vertexes
                                   length:sizeof( vertexes )
                                  options:MTLResourceCPUCacheModeDefaultCache];

id <MTLCommandBuffer> cmd_buffer =     [commandQueue commandBuffer];
id <MTLBlitCommandEncoder> blit_encoder = [cmd_buffer blitCommandEncoder];
[blit_encoder copyFromBuffer:blitBuffer
                    sourceOffset:0
                        toBuffer:buffer
               destinationOffset:0
                            size:sizeof( vertexes )];
[blit_encoder endEncoding];
[cmd_buffer commit];
[cmd_buffer waitUntilCompleted];
```