# Metal craches on MTLDevice.makeBuffer(bytes:length:options:)

Tags: swift, metal

I was working with a simple Metal program for iOS with the book *Metal Programming Guide*, but the `makeBuffer(bytes:length:options:)` does not work as stated in the book.

The related code below

```
let vertexData: [Float] = [
    0.0,  0.5,  0.0,
    -1.0, -0.5,  0.0,
    1.0,  -0.5,  0.0
    ]

let dataSize = vertexData.count * MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: vertexData[0])
vertexBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: vertexData, length: dataSize,
    options: [.storageModePrivate]) // error on this line

...

let renderEncoder = commandBuffer?.makeRenderCommandEncoder(
    descriptor: renderPassDescriptor)
renderEncoder?.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
// skipping other setups
renderEncoder?.endEncoding()
```

will cause a crash during runtime, and here is the error log:

> `` -[MTLDebugDevice newBufferWithBytes:length:options:]:494: failed assertion  `storageModePrivate incompatible with ...WithBytes variant of newBuffer' ``

However, if I use `[]` as the argument for `options` in `makeBuffer(bytes:length:options:)`, the program will work fine:

```
vertexBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: vertexData, length: dataSize,
    options: []) // this will run
```

But why is this the case?

Comment: Storage mode private is for memory that is only accessible by the GPU. In this case I'm not sure why it would be an error, since `makeBuffer(bytes:...)` is supposed to make a copy of the data. In any case, the docs for `makeBuffer(bytes:)` clearly say that private storage mode is not allowed here.

Comment: It's **so** "only accessible by the GPU" that the CPU can't even populate it with the initial data. It would have to make a temporary non-private buffer with the data, create the private buffer, create a command queue, create a command buffer, encode the command to copy from one buffer to the other, commit the command buffer, release the temp buffer, and wait for the command buffer to be completed. The philosophy of Metal is that the API doesn't do surprising things like that behind your back. So, you have to do that yourself.

Comment: @KenThomases I tried to follow the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51159795/macos-mtkview-metal-self-device-newbufferwithbytes-crashes-with-assert , but could not find a correct way to translate Objective-C code to Swift. Could you be more specific how to achieve this in Swift? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm working through the book *Metal Programming Guide* too and ran into this same problem.

I fixed it by changing the storage mode to `.storageModeShared`.

I changed the failing line to:

```swift
vertexBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: vertexData,
                                 length: dataSize,
                                 options: [.storageModeShared]
)
```

After that I was able to get the triangle to render on my phone.